# Get a view in an object using kotlin

Tags: object, kotlin, view

I try to get a reference to an EditText in an object. 
The import `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.dialog_save_recording.dialog_save_recording_edittext_name` doesn't work in the object.

My code:

```
object Dialog {
    fun createDialog(context: Context, layoutId: Int? = null) {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        if (layoutId != null) {
            builder.setView(layoutId)
            builder.setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.dialog_save_button_text)) { _, _ ->
                //get the input of the editText here
            }
  ... //not important for my question
```

The layout I want to reference:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="@dimen/dialog_padding"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dialog_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_save_recording_textview_name"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/dialog_save_recording_name"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dialog_save_recording_edittext_name"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:hint="@string/dialog_save_recording_name_hint"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="text"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I tried it with findViewById or working with the layoutId but had no success for now. I'm searching for a solution without inherit the object from Activity().

Anyone an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You first need to build the dialog:

`val dialog = builder.build()`

Then you can use:

`val editText = dialog.requireViewById(R.id.dialog_save_recording_edittext_name)`

After you apply changes, don't forget to display the dialog:

`dialog.show()`

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! That is what I was looking for! Unfortunately this is just available at API Level 28 and above. Do you know a solution for lower sdk versions?

Comment: It shouldn't be that high, I used it over a year ago. Which part is specified as 28+?

Comment: The requireViewById is underlined in red and the message is "Call requires API Level 28 (current min 24): android.app.Dialog#requireViewById"
So it works with a if statement checking the SDK Version but I need a solution for lower too. Using this on a device with lower SDK the error is: "NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method requireViewById(I)Landroid/view/View; in class Landroid/app/AlertDialog". Any suggestions? :)

Comment: Please try `findViewById` instead.

Comment: It's hard to accept that the answer was that simple. I thank you so much!!